# Django Channels wesbsocket fails on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-channels

I have an app which is deployed to Heroku and uses django channels 3.0.4. It's been running perfectly for the past 18 months but now gives the following error:

WebSocket connection to 'wss://my-app.myurl/ws/quiztest/mc/' failed:

I have not changed any of the code from when it was working previously. I also have a test version of the app running on Heroku using exactly the same codebase and it works fine, which would suggest the error may be to do with my Heroku config, although I've compared the settings of this app with the test app and they seem OK. Everything else in my app works fine, just the django channels websocket issue.

I have spun up a simple test to recreate the issue. Here is the JS that tries to connect:

```
<script>

    var loc = window.location;

    var wsStart = 'ws://';
    if (loc.protocol == 'https:'){
        wsStart = 'wss://';
    }

    var endpoint = wsStart + loc.host + '/ws/quiztest/';
    var username = 'mc';
    var socket = new WebSocket(endpoint + username + '/');
    console.log(socket);
    console.log(endpoint + username + '/');

    socket.onopen = function(e) {
      console.log('Open Host Socket')
    };

    socket.onmessage = function(event) {
      // Handle incoming messages from the server here
      console.log('Received message:', event.data);
    }

    socket.onclose = function(e) {
        console.log('Close',e);
    };

    socket.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log('Error', e);
    };

</script>
```

Here is my routing.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from taskmanager.consumers import MyQuizConsumer

ws_urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/quiztest/<username>/', MyQuizConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

Here is my consumers.py

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer, AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from base.base_helpers import log_and_print

from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

class MyQuizConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def connect(self):
        log_and_print('QUIZ HOST TEST connecting...')

        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            'id-1',
            self.channel_name
        )
        self.accept()
```

Is there anything I might be doing wrong, or are there aspects of my Heroku config I need to check that might cause the websocket to fail?

Comment: Please post a debugging log where the javascript function fails or where the python code fails from the server log. I assume sudo apt get update and pip install --upgrade packagename have not been run since the application stopped working

Comment: The code fails at: var socket = new WebSocket(endpoint + username + '/'); with the error WebSocket connection to 'wss://achieve.hashtag-learning.co.uk/ws/quiztest/mc/' failed: No updates or pip installs have been run since the app stopped working. It did start working again for about 8 days then stopped working again earlier this week. In both cases there had been no code changes, and our staging server which runs a mirror of the code continued working without issue.

Comment: If this staging server runs the code locally but the other server runs the code online then there will be some differences. Is the issued server in 'production' , on the internet?

Comment: @GracenOwnby No, both Staging and Production servers run the same code base on Heroku online. Heroku have come back to say there are no issues at their end and cannot say why we have 2 instances of the same app running the same codebase on Heroku and one works while the other doesn't.

Comment: Im not sure. Heroku uses ubuntu. Ive had trouble with user@1000.service on ubuntu, try running systemctl status user@1000.service

Answer (score 1):

custom ssl settings for channel_layers didn't work for me. I was receiving an error that ssl is an unexpected argument. What did work was to change heroku config var **REDIS_URL** and add **?ssl_cert_reqs=none** in the end

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

So I've resolved this issue. As far as I can tell it was originally caused by my Heroku Redis instance reaching the Maximum Available memory. I upgraded the plan from Mini to Premium-0. However, this also upgraded the Redis instance to 6.2 and I was getting:

SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)

Turns out that [Production plans (Premium and higher) of Heroku Data for Redis running Redis 6+ require TLS connections.](https://help.heroku.com/HC0F8CUS/redis-connection-issues) Heroku Data for Redis uses self-signed certificates and these need to be disabled. This needs to be done for CACHES and both CHANNEL LAYERS.

**CACHES**

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': REDIS_URL,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'CLIENT_CLASS': 'django_redis.client.DefaultClient',
            'IGNORE_EXCEPTIONS': True,
            'CONNECTION_POOL_KWARGS': {
                'ssl_cert_reqs': None
            },

        }
    }
}
```

**CHANNEL LAYERS**

```
import ssl
ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext()
ssl_context.check_hostname = False

heroku_redis_ssl_host = {
    'address': REDIS_URL,
    'ssl': ssl_context
}

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': (heroku_redis_ssl_host,)
        }
    },
}
```